# Why does the horizontal scroll bar always appear in Internet Explorer for this page?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I do not understand why the horizontal scroll bar is always appearing when I open this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="WEEK-S-140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>CONGREGATION NAME</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
        <table class="tableHEADING">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="textCongregation">Congregation Name</td>
                <td class="textTitle">Midweek meeting Schedule</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <a name="week0" />
        <table class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="3">April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="textSpecialEvent" colspan="3">Circuit Assembly - Imitate 
                Jehovah! [09/04/2016] </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="textSpecialEventLocation" colspan="3">Bristol Assembly 
                Hall, Hortham Lane, Bristol, BS32 4JH</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <a name="week1" />
        <table class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Chairman:<br />
                    Auxiliary Classroom Counselor 1: </div>
                April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman<br />
                Counselor 1<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Prayer: </div>
                <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">83</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:23</td>
                <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <a name="week2" />
        <table class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Chairman:<br />
                    Auxiliary Classroom Counselor 1:<br />
                    Auxiliary Classroom Counselor 2: </div>
                April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman<br />
                Counselor 1<br />
                Counselor 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Prayer: </div>
                <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">83</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:23</td>
                <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <br style="page-break-before: always;" />
        <div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
            <table class="tableHEADING">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td class="textCongregation">Congregation Name</td>
                    <td class="textTitle">Midweek meeting Schedule</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <a name="week3" />
        <table class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Chairman: </div>
                April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Prayer: </div>
                <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">83</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:23</td>
                <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableTFGW">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2">
                <div class="textTFGW">
                    TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:33</td>
                <td colspan="1"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
                <td colspan="1"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(8 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student: </div>
                <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible 
                Reading</span> <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)
                </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">ReaderM</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableTFGW">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme2Class" />
                <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2">
                <div class="textTFGW">
                    TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:33</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(8 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student: </div>
                <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible 
                Reading</span> <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)
                </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Reader1</td>
                <td class="cellName">ReaderM</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableTFGW">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme3Class" />
                <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2">
                <div class="textTFGW">
                    TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
                <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 2</td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:33</td>
                <td colspan="3"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
                <td colspan="3"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(8 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student: </div>
                <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible 
                Reading</span> <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less)
                </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Reader1</td>
                <td class="cellName">Reader2</td>
                <td class="cellName">ReaderM</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
                <div class="textAYFM">
                    APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:02</td>
                <td><span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Prepare 
                This Month’s Presentations</span> <span class="textDuration">(15 
                min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
                <div class="textAYFM">
                    APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial 
                Call</span> <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name1M<br />
                Name1MA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:54</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Return 
                Visit</span> <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name2M<br />
                Name2MA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:01</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible 
                Study</span> <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name3M<br />
                Name3MA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <table class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
        </table>
        <table class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme2Class" />
                <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
                <div class="textAYFM">
                    APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial 
                Call</span> <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name11<br />
                Name11A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name1M<br />
                Name1MA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:54</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Return 
                Visit</span> <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name21<br />
                Name21A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name2M<br />
                Name2MA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:01</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible 
                Study</span> <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name31<br />
                Name31A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name3M<br />
                Name3MA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <table class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
        </table>
        <table class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme3Class" />
                <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
                <div class="textAYFM">
                    APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
                <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 2</td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial 
                Call</span> <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name11<br />
                Name11A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name12<br />
                Name12A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name1M<br />
                Name1MA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:54</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Return 
                Visit</span> <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name21<br />
                Name21A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name22<br />
                Name22A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name2M<br />
                Name2MA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:01</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant: </div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible 
                Study</span> <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Name31<br />
                Name31A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name32<br />
                Name32A</td>
                <td class="cellName">Name3M<br />
                Name3MA</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableLAC">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellLAC" colspan="3">
                <div class="textLAC">
                    LIVING AS CHRISTIANS</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:07</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">42</span> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:17</td>
                <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 
                1</span> <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:22</td>
                <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 
                2</span> <span class="textDuration">(5 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:52</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Conductor:<br />
                    Reader: </div>
                <span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Congregation 
                Bible Study </span><span class="textDuration">(30 min.)</span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Conductor<br />
                Reader</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:55</td>
                <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Review/Preview/Announcements</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">21:00</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Prayer: </div>
                <span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">65</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="tableLAC">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellLAC" colspan="3">
                <div class="textLAC">
                    LIVING AS CHRISTIANS</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:07</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">42</span> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:17</td>
                <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 
                1</span> <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:22</td>
                <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 
                2</span> <span class="textDuration">(5 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:25</td>
                <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Review/Preview/Announcements</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:55</td>
                <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Service 
                Talk Theme</span> <span class="textDuration">(30 min.) </span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">Circuit Overseer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">21:00</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Prayer: </div>
                <span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">65</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">Brother 8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* Column widths */
.columnTime {
    width: 7%;
}

.columnTheme1Class {
    width: 76%;
}

.columnTheme2Classes {
    width: 64%;
}

.columnTheme3Classes {
    width: 52%;
}

.columnName {
    width: 17%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
    /* This is the default font for all cells */
    font-family: Calibri;
}

table tbody tr:hover td {
    color: #000;
    background: #efefef;
}

body{
    width:100%;
    background: #666;
}

.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}

.containerMeeting {

}

.cellBibleReading {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}

.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}

.tableHEADINGOuter {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}

.tableHEADING {
}

.tableHEADING td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 4px gray solid;
}

.textSpecialEvent {
    text-align: center;
}

.textSpecialEventLocation {
    text-align: center;
}

.tableDATE {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}

.tableTFGW {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}

.cellTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}

.textTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #606a70;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bulletTFGW {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #606a70;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.tableAYFM {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}

.cellAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}

.textAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bulletAYFM {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #c18626;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.cellClass {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: gray;
}

.tableLAC {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}

.cellLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}

.textLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #961526;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bulletLAC {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #961526;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textDuration {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textTheme {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textSongLabel {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textSongNumber {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textCongregation {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.textTitle {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

@media print {
    body{
        background: #FFF;
    }

    .containerPage, .containerMeeting, .tableDATE, .tableHEADINGOuter, .tableHEADING, .tableTFGW, .tableAYFM, .tableLAC, {
        width: 99%;
        min-width: 99%;
        max-width: 99%;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left:0;
        margin-right:0;
    }
}
```

[image: Internet Explorer scroll bar issue]

As you can see, even with a very wide screen and full maximized view I get a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Hi Andrew, you need to add your CSS to the question itself, rather than linking to a file download.

Comment: I have now added the CSS into the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your body element is set to 100%, but the margin is making it > 100%.

Adding margin: 0px to the body CSS should fix it.

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #666;
}
```

And also, the print section had to be adjusted so **Print Preview** would still be OK:

```
@media print {
    body{
        background: #FFF;
    }

    .containerPage, .containerMeeting, .tableDATE, .tableHEADINGOuter, .tableHEADING, .tableTFGW, .tableAYFM, .tableLAC, {
        width: 99%;
        min-width: 99%;
        max-width: 99%;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
}
```

The margins needed to be set to **auto**.

Comment: That does fix it, thank you. However, I seem to have a side effect when I try to print preview. Now the report is not center of page.

Comment: How about

 @media screen {
   body {
     margin: 0px;
   }
 }

You'd want to remove margin: 0px from the other body CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I must have something else wrong with it now. Perhaps it should be a separate question.

Comment: I think this is now a CHtmlView quirk as it opens directly in IE and previews fine. Just in the web-browser control is doesn't.

Comment: I had to adjust the @media print { .containerPage ... } section and set the magins there to auto.